# How to create custom preferences?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

After long struggle i am posting this question with hope where i will get answer to my question.

I can't able to create custom `preferences` activity with background image, view bars between every preference,.

As i had designed one custom preferences page but i cant able to make preference cell as button and i cant able to add key values to preferences to make them as `sharedpreferences`, even i tried with `preferencesfragment` also, but i couldn't able to make it work.

Please help me from this custom preferences activity.

Comment: I would also like to know, how I can repair mine.
I would show some code inside the pastebin, because I use board account-manager, authenticator service and custom preferences. Though, a) they look bad, b) the account cannot be changed if once created, c) if I delete the account the credentials are not deleted.
But for OP: Check this links:http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html.

Comment: You are asking way to much.

Comment: what do you mean Mr.greenapps the question what i asked is very clear..

Comment: have you checked http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture12/lecture12.html for PreferenceFragment?